# The server fail ed to resume the transaction. Desc:9800000002. (3971) (SQLEndTran)')

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, transactions

What I'm trying to do is push the data frame in the SQL server using the `pd.to_sql` method.
langyuage- python 3.6, pandas version `pandas(0.25.1)`

Engine variable

`engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s"%PARAM,pool_size = 20,max_overflow =10,pool_recycle=60,pool_timeout=30)`

this is the main script which is calling `staging_standardisation()` method.

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,event
import pandas as pd
from utils import engine

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def plugin_bef_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context,executemany):
   if executemany:
       cursor.fast_executemany = True  # replace from execute many to fast_executemany.
       cursor.commit()

table = "table_name"
column_name = ["Some column_names"] #selecting some columns names

column_obj = {"a":"A",
              "b":"B",
              "c":"C"
              }

staging_standardisation(engine=engine, table_name=table, column_names=column_name, column_obj=column_obj)
```

staging_standardisation method

```
def staging_standardisation(engine, table_name, column_names, column_obj, **kwargs):
    try:
        query = "SELECT * FROM  dbo.License_Search"
        sql_df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
        df = sql_df[column_names]
        df = df.rename(index=str, columns=column_obj)
        try:
            if 'authority_id' in column_obj.values():
                pass
            else:

                df['authority_id'] =53

        except KeyError:
            df['authority_id'] = None
    try:
        df.to_sql(name=staging_table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append') # this line causing error.

    except Exception as exe:
        print(table_name, exe)
```

Throwing error

```
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:8c00000007. 
(3971) (SQLEndTran); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The 
transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session. (3926)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: `query="SELECT id "+"FROM table_name"+"WHERE name="+"'"+"{0}".format(authority_name)+"'"+";"` is a mess. It's also exposed to SQL injection. But `"SELECT id "+"FROM table_name"` baffles me; why would you even try to concat those strings and not just make it a single string?

Comment: `query = "SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE name = %s", authority_id`. But I can't follow this at all.

Comment: @roganjosh I have modified (set df['authority_id'] =53(, `query = "SELECT * FROM  dbo.License_Search"`  the code and ran it again facing the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the casting. In dataframe date(column) type was a string. then I converted column type to DateTime.

FYI: error showed by vs code is limited. we ran a separate test in jupyter notebook where we had full error and found that it was date column

```
def staging_standardisation(engine, table_name, column_names, column_obj, **kwargs):
    try:
        query = "SELECT * FROM  dbo.License_Search"
        sql_df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
        df = sql_df[column_names]
        df = df.rename(index=str, columns=column_obj)
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        try:
            if 'authority_id' in column_obj.values():
                pass
            else:

                df['authority_id'] =53

        except KeyError:
            df['authority_id'] = None
    try:
        df.to_sql(name=staging_table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append') # this line causing error.

    except Exception as exe:
        print(table_name, exe)
```

[For more info read this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2009/02/24/the-server-failed-to-resume-the-transaction-why/)